# How to echo a variable containing an unescaped dollar sign in bash

Tags: bash, escaping, dollar-sign

If I have a variable containing an unescaped dollar sign, is there any way I can echo the entire contents of the variable?

For example something calls a script:

`./script.sh "test1$test2"`

and then if I want to use the parameter it gets "truncated" like so:

`echo ${1}

test1`

Of course single-quoting the varaible name doesn't help.  I can't figure out how to quote it so that I can at least escape the dollar sign myself once the script recieves the parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The variable is replaced before the script is run.

```
./script.sh 'test1$test2'
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the case :)

Comment: There are other situations though where I actually have variables with unescaped dollar signs, like when I'm reading data from files.  I then want to call my script with this data, so is it my only option to sed the entire file before reading it?

Comment: Reading data from files does not do variable substitution.

Answer (score 32):

The problem is that script receives "test1" in the first place and it cannot possibly know that there was a reference to an empty (undeclared) variable. You have to escape the `$` before passing it to the script, like this:

```
./script.sh "test1\$test2"
```

Or use single quotes `'` like this:

```
./script.sh 'test1$test2'
```

In which case bash will not expand variables from that parameter string.

Answer (score 4):

by using single quotes , meta characters like `$` will retain its literal value. If double quotes are used, variable names will get interpolated.

Answer (score 0):

As Ignacio told you, the variable is replaced, so your scripts gets `./script.sh test1` as values for `$0` and `$1`.

But even in the case you had used literal quotes to pass the argument, you shoudl always quote `"$1"` in your `echo "${1}"`. This is a good practice.

Comment: And the braces are *not* needed, since this is a simple substitution.