# how to embed real '$' char in bash string

Tags: bash

i want to print real '$' char to string in bash

for example :
 `echo "abc$acb" > a.txt`
when the second "abc" is not treated as variable.

is it Possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to echo a variable containing an unescaped dollar sign in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923623/how-to-echo-a-variable-containing-an-unescaped-dollar-sign-in-bash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to prevent **expansion**, you simply escape it with `\` i.e. `echo "abc\$acb" > a.txt`

Or, another option is to use **single quotes**: `echo 'abc$acb' > a.txt`

Answer (score 3):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes which wont evaluate $.

```
echo 'abc$acb' > a.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

escape it as in:

```
echo "abc\$acb"
```