# Echo content of a string variable containing a dollar

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have seen [How to echo a variable containing an unescaped dollar sign in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923623/how-to-echo-a-variable-containing-an-unescaped-dollar-sign-in-bash) 
However, my case is slightly different.

I have my variable var
I want to echo the content of the variable var.
A command such as

```
echo ${var}
```

or

```
echo "${var}"
```

is globally fine

However, in one case, this variable took the value

```
var=abdc$32
```

And in this specific case, my echo does not work as it does not print `abcd$32` as expected as it interprets the `$` sign

I am not the one assigning the value for the variable, that is why an assignment

```
var='abcd$32'
```

cannot be done.

The variable is actually a password I extract from the Jenkins Credential Binding plugin 'see https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/).

Syntax :

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'my_credential', passwordVariable: 'MY_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'MY_USERNAME')]) 
{
                   sh "echo MY_PASSWORD ${MY_PASSWORD} "  
}
```

If I put a single quote,

```
 sh 'echo MY_PASSWORD ${MY_PASSWORD} '
```

the password would be hidden (which is what you would actually expect from the plugin).

How could I do so that I can echo the real content of the var MY_PASSWORD ?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [mre]. The problem likely occurs when the variable is assigned rather than when it's evaluated. Please [edit] your question to include your code, sample input and output, and any error messages. Tell us what you expect to happen as well as what's actually happening. This will help us answer your question better.

Comment: the dollar sign is being interpreted during the assignment: `var=abcd$32`; see Giles answer re: using single quotes

Comment: I did not give the full context. I am not the one assigning the value for the variable, that is why var='abcd$32' cannot be done.  The variable is actually a password I extract from the Jenkins Credential Binding plugin 'see https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/) .  Syntax :    withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: 'mylogin', variable: 'USERPASS')]) {
    sh '' echo $USERPASS"  }

Comment: Add this crucial information by [editing your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62305772/edit) ans add more context (`JenkinsFile`)

Comment: The password belongs not to be 'echoed' but to be use in your code. Why do you want to `echo` it while Jenkins prevent password leak ?

Comment: I needed to retrieve in a quick manner all the credentials in my Jenkins system. I noticed there was a "flaw" in the Jenkins plugin as the echo allowed to display the password. I then noticed that it worked for all passwords, except for a password that contained a "$" in it . That is why I am asking this question. I do realize the answer is probably not in shell syntax but probably in the plugin itself. However, it is likely that the best answer they can give is that it should not display anything anyway. But anyway, thank you all for your answer and your time. It was still useful.

Comment: Calling Jenkins REST API maybe expose passwords in a clean way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in comments by [@markp-fuso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7366100/markp-fuso), the dollar sign is being interpreted during the assignment: `var=abcd$32`

This is the shell quoting basics, so, instead:

```
 var='abdc$32'
 echo "$var"
```

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
>   http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: see my comment above. I cannot do the assignment part as I actually get the var from a binding plugin.

Comment: **If** the variable contains a literal `$`, echo will display it.  The assignment is just an example. For instance, if you do a `var=$(head -n 1 myfile)`, and the first line in the file contains _abcd$12_, then a `echo $var` also displays the `$` unexpanded. If you don't see a `$` in the output, there was already no `$` in the variable (which you can verify in bash by doing a `xxd <<<"$var"`)

Comment: I'll consider this answer as the "right" answer in order to close the case. The discussion allowed me to find what was wrong.  Thank you all